Preface and ToC: multiple entries, and tocloft causes preface to appear at end to the ToC
I am using bookdown to produce a book... as one does. But the table of contents in the LaTeX/PDF version is giving me conniptions.
I cannot get things right...
For example, in a minimal dummy project, if I have in the index.Rmd file:
\frontmatter

# Preface

the TOC is fine:

However, the Preface appears with a massive Chapter 0 indicator:

No surprise; that's what one expects... so instead:
\frontmatter

# Preface {-}

But this now produces two Preface entries in the ToC for some reason:

Hmm. That's my first unresolved issue: why two?
Ultimately, I want to use tocloft to add some space between the section numbers and the section titles in the ToC, so something like this in preamble.tex:
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em }% ToC: Set width to the section number 

Seems reasonable.
But if I do include the tocloft package (which I want to do in the real document; not necessary in the dummy one), one of these "Preface" ToC entries appears at the end of the ToC:

I'm obviously doing something dumb to end up in this pickle, but I cannot figure out what's going on.
Any advice appreciate. I want "Preface" to appear once in the ToC, at the start... and just appearing as an unnumbered section in the \frontmatter before the \mainmatter.
Repos of minimal example at: https://github.com/PeterKDunn/BookTest
Thanks.
P.

Please add a compilable [mre] to your question.

I have it all in the minimal repos.

Question here have to be self-sustained to ensure they remain useful for users with the same problem in the event that the link stops working

And how can one do that for a bookdown project? I have no idea where the error is coming from, so what specific files to post.

I (disclaimer: author of bookdown) think a link to a Github repo is totally reasonable in this specific case (thanks @Pete for the effort). Posting all files here would be a disaster to people who want to help, since it'd be very inconvenient to run the reproducible example---you'd have to copy the content of each file, create each file, paste, and save them. That's simply a waste of time. I understand why SO asks for questions to be self-contained, but please, please allow exceptions occasionally. BTW, not sure who voted to close the question, but I see absolutely no reason to close it.

For the tocloft issue, I suggest you give it up (i.e. don't use this package). From my experience of publishing five books with this obscure krantz.cls, you won't have much luck or hope to resolve the LaTeX issue on your own or with other experts. Only one person in the world maintains this document class (and probably only he understands it), i.e., Chapman & Hall's help desk. If you really want to figure it out, you can prepare a minimal reproducible .tex file (_book/_main.tex and your krantz.cls) and ask him.

Thanks @YihuiXie; I had assumed using krantz.cls would be non-negotiable. I'll chase that up.

It's non-negotiable indeed if you publish with them, but as I said, they do have a LaTeX help desk. To be fair, the help desk has always been helpful, but the pain is that you will likely run into trouble as soon as you start customizing your book with extra LaTeX packages or commands. I'll negotiate with them about the possibility of printing books from HTML early next year after I finish the documentation of litedown. I've been fed up with LaTeX problems.

I can't answer the tocloft question. To prevent Preface from appearing twice, you can add an attribute .unlisted to the heading, e.g.,
# Preface {.unnumbered .unlisted}

